# Spring TestRestTemplate postForEntity won't do redirect even with HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS set

Tags: spring-mvc, testing, redirect, post, get

I'm using Post-Redirect-Get controllers with Spring's `RedirectView`, `RedirectAttributes` and `addFlashAttributes`. The redirects work manually using browser. However, I can't test this redirect through to the redirected controller using `TestRestTemplate`. `TestRestTemplate` does not perform the redirect even if I set `HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS` in it (enabling it actually has no effect). While `testRestTemplate.postForEntity(...)` returns `302 FOUND` status and location of redirect, I don't get the flashAttributes from `@PostMapping` controller so I can't reuse them in a second call to simulate the redirect to the `@GetMapping` controller.

I know these flashAttributes can be obtained using `MockMVC`. However, I'm trying to do integration testing all the way through to a test database and back to forms and views.

- If I'm not setting the `HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS` correctly,
  please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
- If there is a different way to
  declare it (maybe using the Http request in the `postForEntity`),
  please describe.
- If there is a different way to get TestRestTemplate
  to allow/complete the redirects, what is it?
- If no way to do this
  (least preferred), is there at least a way to configure
  TestRestTemplate to return flashAttributes so I can use them in a separate get
  call to the location returned in the ResponseEntity headers?

Here's the applicable parts of the PRG controllers:

```
@GetMapping(value={"/view"})
public String getMyentityView(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
{
    Myentity myentity = null;
    //use RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request) to get custom "success" flashAttributes and add to model
    //Do view processing 
    model.addAttribute("myentity", myentity);
    return "eMyentityView";
}

//@GetMapping controller to get the form "/form" not incl for brevity

@PostMapping(value = {"/submit"})
public RedirectView myentitySubmit(@ModelAttribute("myentity") Myentity myentity, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirAttrs) {
    validator.validate(myentity, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX+"myentity", bindingResult);
        redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("myentity", myentity);
        return new RedirectView("/form", true);
    }
    ...
    //Handle good new myentity, save, add custom "success" messages to flashAttributes, etc.
    ...
    return new RedirectView("/view", true);
}
```

Here's the test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, useMainMethod = UseMainMethod.ALWAYS)
//Other annotations
public class ElectionCrudIntegrationTests {

   ....

   @Test
   @Order(0020)
   void givenTestMyentityWhenSubmitThenExpectedViewDataReturned() throws Exception {

       //Get test entity from test data
       Myentity tempMyentity = testData.getGoodTestData().get("test-myentity-001");
    
       //Create test client
       RestTemplateBuilder rtb = new RestTemplateBuilder().rootUri("http://localhost:7777");
       TestRestTemplate trt = new TestRestTemplate(rtb, null, null, TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS);
    
       //No redirect occurs with this call - request returns after completing myentitySubmit method
       //HttpRequester.makeMyEntityHttpRequest(tempMyentity) adds myentity props to request map 
       //(is there is a way to allow redirects in postForEntity's HttpRequest???)
       ResponseEntity<String> responseSubmit = this.trt.postForEntity("/submit",
            HttpRequester.makeMyEntityHttpRequest(tempMyentity), String.class);
    
       //These asserts pass
       assertEquals(HttpStatus.FOUND, responseSubmit.getStatusCode());
       assertEquals("http://localhost:7777/view",
            responseSubmit.getHeaders().get("Location").get(0).split(";")[0]);
       //But I get null body and no flashAttributes in the headers
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Spring's strategy for handling redirects is to do two calls whether you use TestRestTemplate or MockMvc. See [the github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18914).
Given that, MockMvc appears to provide the most functionality to do everything that needs to be done including grabbing the flashAttributes and links from the Post call, testing them and then resubmitting it back to the Get call. This can be done by:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, useMainMethod = UseMainMethod.ALWAYS)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//Other annotations
public class ElectionCrudIntegrationTests {
  ....

  @Test
  @Order(0020)
  void givenTestMyentityWhenSubmitThenExpectedViewDataReturned() throws Exception {

      //Get test entity from test data
      Myentity tempMyentity = testData.getGoodTestData().get("test-myentity-001");

      //Add form properties (or whole entity) using MockMvc .param tools
      MvcResult mv = mvc.perform(post("/submit")
        .param("tempMyentityPropName", "tempMyentityPropValue"))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()
        .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/view"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.flash()
        .attributeExists("MyCustomAttrName"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.flash()
        .attributeExists("MyEntityAttrName"))//Or BindingResult...
        .andReturn();

      //Grab data from response to do something (or not)
      MyCustomAttr custom = (MyCustomAttr) mv.getFlashMap().get("MyCustomAttrName");
      MyEntity myentity = (MyEntity) mv.getFlashMap().get("MyEntityAttrName");
      FlashMap flashMap = mv.getFlashMap();
      String redirectUrl = mv.getResponse().getRedirectedUrl();

      //Do the redirect call 
      mvc.perform(get(redirectUrl).flashAttrs(flashMap))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("eMyentityView"));

      //Instead of using the andReturn() and grabbing data, it's probably possible to complete the second perform directly with linked functions.

  }
  ...
```

}

According to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/spring-mvc-test-framework/server-htmlunit.html), there are two options to analyze forms with MockMvc. You can use either HtmlUnit or Selenium's WebDriver. WebDriver has quit a bit of functionality and MockMvc should provide Thymeleaf and other view response (but maybe not jsp). The documentation explains how to integrate these tools into your tests.